# "This program cannot be run in DOS mode" - meaning in installshield

Tags: installshield-2011

I have built Basic MSI in InstallShield 2011. I have .NET Installer class in my project. When I install the .msi I am getting Error 1001 and rolls back. A temp file "TBD8BEA.tmp" is created in ProgramFiles folder. Temp file has binary content but has a sentence "This program cannot be run in DOS mode." What is the reason for this error and what is the solution. Pls Help me.

Comment: Open Notepad. Open *any* executable (.EXE). You'll find the message "This program cannot be run in DOS mode" - it's a standard part of every Windows executable.

Answer (score 1):

The text "This program cannot be run in DOS mode" is the string that is displayed when you try to run a Windows executable in, you guessed it, DOS mode. I would guess that your .tmp file is probably executable. The message is not an error message; rather, it's part of the executable program's data. You can verify this by opening various other executables in a hex editor; that's where I recognized it from.

Other than that, you should probably give some more information and/or examples of what you tried - the question is somewhat on the unspecific side for people to be able to help you.